# Changing mouseover effect on Mahapps Tile

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox, mahapps.metro

So recently I've started using MahApps.Metro for an application.
It's been going great, but one problem I cannot solve is **MouseOver effect on a Tile**.

I have a Grid, in which there's an Expander that hosts all the Tiles each of which represent a connection to the specific database. They are bound to an **ObservableCollection** which I populate from another database.

```
<Grid>
    <Expander Margin="5" Header="Server Connections">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OmsConnections}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:Tile
                        Title="{Binding Name}"
                        controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
                        Background="{DynamicResource GrayBrush2}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.TileClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        HorizontalTitleAlignment="Left"
                        Style="{StaticResource LargeTileStyle}"
                        TiltFactor="2">
                        <Image
                            Width="60"
                            Height="60"
                            Source="{Binding OmsConnectionTypeId, Converter={StaticResource ConnectionTypeToIconConverter}}" />
                    </controls:Tile>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

This is the style applied via Style

```
    <Style x:Key="LargeTileStyle" TargetType="controls:Tile">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
        <Setter Property="TitleFontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
        <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="210" />
    </Style>
```

So Whenever I mouseover an item I get the black border as specified, and this Orange Background Color (Which, if I'm not mistaken, is AccentColorBrush3) and I have no idea how to change it.

[Here's the Image, since my rep is low and i cannot embed it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idn9p.png)

Also, I'm really, really bad with Templates and Styles, so this is pretty much what i scrapped from the internet. ANY Feedback would be much appreciated for both the way I Bound to a collection and how to change the MouseOver color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "override" the `AccentColorBrush3` resource by adding a `SolidColorBrush` resource to the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OmsConnections}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <!-- Specify the highlight brush here: -->
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush3" Color="Yellow" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:Tile
                        Title="{Binding Name}"
                        controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
                        Background="{DynamicResource GrayBrush2}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.TileClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        HorizontalTitleAlignment="Left"
                        Style="{StaticResource LargeTileStyle}"
                        TiltFactor="2">
                <Image  Width="60"
                        Height="60"
                        Source="{Binding OmsConnectionTypeId, Converter={StaticResource ConnectionTypeToIconConverter}}" />
            </controls:Tile>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
Of course during the weekend I bailed on work, but today this solved my question. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome but please remember to accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I will, forgot it. :) Thanks again.